# Как сохранить документ используя IText7

Tags: c#, itext

Я добавил в документ гиперссылку:

```
using Kernel = iText.Kernel;
using Pdf = iText.Kernel.Pdf;


Pdf.PdfReader reader = new Pdf.PdfReader(fileName);
Pdf.PdfDocument document = new Pdf.PdfDocument(reader);

// Creating a PdfLinkAnnotation object 
Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rect = new Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
Pdf.Annot.PdfLinkAnnotation annotation = new Pdf.Annot.PdfLinkAnnotation(rect);
// Setting action of the annotation 
Pdf.Action.PdfAction action = Pdf.Action.PdfAction.CreateURI("http://www.mail.ru/");
annotation.SetAction(action);
annotation.SetHighlightMode(Pdf.Annot.PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
annotation.SetBorder(new Pdf.PdfArray(new int[] { 0, 0, 1 }));
document.GetPage(1).AddAnnotation(annotation);
document.Close();
```

Как можно сохранить документ?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже просто перезаписать файл в IText7 нельзя. Можно открыть файл в stamping mode. Записать в документ гиперссылку, а затем заменить старый документ на новый.

Answer (score 0):

> using Kernel = iText.Kernel; using Pdf = iText.Kernel.Pdf;
>
> Pdf.PdfReader reader = new Pdf.PdfReader(fileName); string curDir =
> Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); string workFile = curDir +
> "\work.pdf"; Pdf.PdfWriter writer = new Pdf.PdfWriter(workFile);
> Pdf.PdfDocument document = new Pdf.PdfDocument(reader, writer);
>
> // Creating a PdfLinkAnnotation object  Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rect =
> new Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0); Pdf.Annot.PdfLinkAnnotation
> annotation = new Pdf.Annot.PdfLinkAnnotation(rect); // Setting action
> of the annotation  Pdf.Action.PdfAction action =
> Pdf.Action.PdfAction.CreateURI("http://www.mail.ru/");
> annotation.SetAction(action);
> annotation.SetHighlightMode(Pdf.Annot.PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
> annotation.SetBorder(new Pdf.PdfArray(new int[] { 0, 0, 1 }));
> document.GetPage(1).AddAnnotation(annotation); document.Close();
>
> // Заменяю старый документ на новый string newPath =
> fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4) + "_old.pdf";
> File.Move(fileName, newPath); File.Move(workFile, fileName);